# tokenizing a metafield

Tags: php, javascript, sql, mysql, ajax

I am working with a CMS like system, which has a special field defined for use in its forms.

This field works similarly to google suggest, executing an sql query behind the scenes and displaying results.

The SQL query I am using selects 3 fields from table1, and concatenates them as a result.

What I need to do, is split this new metafield back into 3 distinct fields, so I can insert them into table2 along with the rest of the form.

How would I go about doing this normally in PHP? Javascript? Inbuilt PHP functionality?

I do wonder how much leeway I have as I am using provided input fields, not standard input fields.

Comment: I'm really dumb... couldn't understand anything.

Comment: How do you concatenate your fields, do you use any separator? If yes, use PHP's explode('SEPARATOR', $concataenated) way to get fields as an array.

Comment: I have a field which displays results as i type, ala google suggest. The result is 3 fields concatenated together. I need to separate them again to be able to insert them into separate fields in a new table.

Comment: yes... but how are the concatenated? Can you show us an example?

Comment: err, I don´t know that that is relevant? The sql snippet would be CONCAT(guests.firstname,' ',guests.lastname) - so what is returned in the metafield is Bob Parsons for example. I then need to split this up so I can insert Bob into firstname and Parsons into lastname.

Comment: If the separator returned is only a space, you will only be able to separate words and not fields. If the name of the person is 'Mary Ann Parsons' you will only be able to separate as Mary to name and Ann to lastname and Parsons will stay out... or you will put Ann Parsons as lastname. You need to act before the concatenation takes place to save the fields properly or to change the ' ' to ';' for example.

Comment: I am aware of that, and it is no problem for me to add a comma to use a delimiter instead of a space. My problem is with actually accessing the content of the field in the first place.

Comment: Do CONCAT(guests.firstname,' ',guests.lastname) AS fullname

Then you can access the value in PHP by $row['fullname']

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is that you want the "autocomplete" field to automatically fill out the form with the values of the fields when selected? If so, you probably either need to change the separator to something that can be easily split using Javascript (such as "|") or modify the SQL query and PHP code to ouput the 3 fields separately as well. This may be harder if you haven't written the autocomplete code yourself

Comment: I don´t want the autocomplete field to automatically fill out the form, i want to use the one autocomplete field in place of having seperate textboxes for firstname and lastname. To do this, I need a way to make the text in the autocomplete field be broken up and inserted into firstname and lastname. The problem isn´t what I use as a delimiter(not yet anyway), its to access that field in the first place.

Comment: If you manage to post the full field (firstname|lastname) as a single value, you can modify the PHP code that handles the information. 

Example:

<input name="name" value="john|smith">

Then you can access the individual values by splitting the field with the PHP code that receives the values:

$fields = explode("|",$_POST['name']);
$firstname = $fields[0];
$lastname = count($fields) > 1 ? $fields[1] : "";

Alternatively you could of course split the fields using javascript and save them in separate hidden input fields (<input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="john">)