# Javascript not loading for php generated form

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms, phpbms

I am using phpBMS, and have made a form, similar to the [sample provided](http://www.phpbms.org/browser/trunk/phpbms/modules/sample/sampletable_addedit.php).

Using the provided input fields, I have made a basic dropdown list containing two items, and a checkbox.

I want the checkbox to be selected automatically when one of the options from the dropdown box is selected.

Jens F, provided me with a solution to how I should do this in javascript [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155984/setting-the-value-of-a-checkbox-based-on-what-is-selected-in-a-list).

However, for some reason I can not get the javascript to execute.

I have the javascript in a file called checkpaid.js, which is included in my form. Using firebug I can see that the javscript file is fetched, and it appears in the list of scripts, but it is absolutely never executed at all.

How would I start to figure out why it is not executing, when it is clearly being included in the page?

[Here](http://www.phpbms.org/browser/trunk/phpbms/modules/bms/javascript/addresstorecord.js?rev=767) is an example of the provided javascript for an existing form, which takes an action if a radio button is clicked.

Here is my current form and javascript:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

    include("../../include/session.php");
    include("include/tables.php");
    include("include/fields.php");

    include("include/sales.php");

    if(!isset($_GET["backurl"]))
        $backurl = NULL;
    else{
        $backurl = $_GET["backurl"];
        if(isset($_GET["refid"]))
            $backurl .= "?refid=".$_GET["refid"];
    }

    $thetable = new sales($db, "tbld:490cf2d1-1c72-7b99-461d-b1b8e68553c4");
    $therecord = $thetable->processAddEditPage();

    if(isset($therecord["phpbmsStatus"]))
        $statusmessage = $therecord["phpbmsStatus"];

    $pageTitle = "Sales";

    $phpbms->cssIncludes[] = "pages/menus.css";
    $phpbms->jsIncludes[] = "modules/base/javascript/menu.js";
    $phpbms->jsIncludes[] = "modules/micro hospitality/javascript/checkpaid.js";

    $phpbms->onload[] = "initializePage()";

        $theform = new phpbmsForm();

        $theinput = new inputSmartSearch($db, "chooseguests", "Choose Guests",NULL, "Choose Guest", TRUE, NULL, NULL, TRUE, $required=true);
        $theinput->setAttribute("class","important");
        $theform->addField($theinput);

        $theinput = new inputSmartSearch($db, "chooseproducts", "Choose Product",NULL, "Choose Product", TRUE, NULL, NULL, TRUE, $required=true);
        $theinput->setAttribute("class","important");
        $theform->addField($theinput);

        $theinput = new inputField("quantity",$therecord["quantity"],"Quantity",true, NULL, 1);
        $theinput->setAttribute("class","important");
        $theform->addField($theinput);

        $theinput = new inputBasicList("type",$therecord["paymenttype"],array("Cash"=>"cash","Credit"=>"credit"), "Payment Type");
        $theinput->setAttribute("class","important");
        $theform->addField($theinput);

        $theinput = new inputCheckbox("paid", $therecord["paid"], "Paid");
        $theform->addField($theinput);

        $theinput = new inputField("receiptno",$therecord["receiptno"],"Receipt No",true, NULL, 10);
        $theinput->setAttribute("class","important");
        $theform->addField($theinput);

        $thetable->getCustomFieldInfo();
        $theform->prepCustomFields($db, $thetable->customFieldsQueryResult, $therecord);
        $theform->jsMerge();

    include("header.php");

?><div class="bodyline">

    <?php $theform->startForm($pageTitle)?>

    <div id="leftSideDiv">
        <fieldset>
            <legend><label for="S">Sales</label></legend>

            <p class="big"><?php $theform->showField("chooseguests"); ?></p>
            <p class="big"><?php $theform->showField("chooseproducts"); ?></p>
            <p class="big"><?php $theform->showField("quantity"); ?></p>
            <p class="big"><?php $theform->showField("type"); ?></p>
            <p class="big"><?php $theform->showField("paid"); ?></p>
            <p class="big"><?php $theform->showField("receiptno"); ?></p>


        </fieldset>

    </div>
    <?php
        $theform->showGeneralInfo($phpbms,$therecord);
        $theform->endForm();
    ?>
</div>
<?php include("footer.php");?>


------------------
checkpaid.js: 

window.addEvent('domready', function(){
  $('type').addEvent('change',function(){
    if($(this).get('value') == 'credit') {
      $('paid').set('checked','checked');
    } else {
      $('paid').removeProperty('checked');
    }
  });
});
alert("loaded");
```

Comment: What JavaScript library are you using?  I.e. what's providing the domready event hook?

Comment: phpBMS uses mootools, which is what that is meant to be using. It does actualy work outside of phpbms fine.

Comment: make sure that the ID of the dropdown is in fact "type", you can put an alert statement or "console.log("executed") inside the change event to see if that piece of code is in fact executing. If it isn't - post a url of the page so I can investiage a tad further.

Comment: I can´t provide you with access to my page..I would, but I am behind NAT and don´t have access to change it. The ID is definitly type as you can see in my form, and it is confirmed in the output HTML. I put both an alert and console.log("executed"), and it definitly does not seem to be executing at all...but I can´t figure out why?

Comment: Check the console for errors.  Also, verify that the mootools library is indeed being loaded.

Comment: mootools is indeed being loaded, all all the ajaxy goodness would not work. There are absolutely no errors. The js file is loaded, but never utilized.

Comment: OK, progress, javascript warnings reports: window.addEvent is not a function in checkpaid.js

Comment: window.addEvent is not a function
http://localhost/1/phpbms/modules/micro%20hospitality/javascript/checkpaid.js
Line 1

Comment: Is checkpaid.js somehow being included before mootools?

Comment: No, I don´t see how that would be possible. See in my form above, I include it after menu.js

Comment: Compare it to menu.js which is provided by phpBMS and also included in my form...it seems to refer to input fields and such in an entirely different way: http://phpbms.com/browser/trunk/phpbms/modules/base/javascript/menu.js

Comment: If I wrap what is currently in checkpaid.js in a function, the error goes away, but then I get no new errors or warnings and it still does not work.

Comment: Well, it seems that whatever is supposed to provide window.addEvent() is not working.  I'm pretty sure that this is provided by mootools, hence my wondering if checkpaid.js is being executed before mootools.

Comment: is there a way to include mootools in checkpaid.js? Also why would wrapping it in a function eliminate errors? Is it not possible there is a seperate way to try and do what I want to do that phpBMS understands, going by how menu.js is implemented?

Comment: I've downloaded phpbms and it doesn't use addEvent() anywhere.  Nor does it seem to include anything from mootools that would provide it.  It seems to only use moo.fx.js.  I think you need to download mootool.js yourself and include that, as you do checkpaid.js, and -- of coruse -- include it before checkpaid.js.

Comment: Hmm, I downloaded mootools-1.2.4-core-nc.js and included it before checkpaid.js, but in the console log that file itself generates errors, and still no errors or anything from checkpaid.js - even though phpbms does not window.addevent anywhere, surely it has mootools...in the moo folder in common\javascript\moo although that appears to be moo FX pack which is maybe differenr from moo tools

Comment: Yes, phpbms does not seem to use the full mootools library.

Comment: well, including the moofiles.js still does not, and also breaks my smart search field I have on the form. Would there be another way to do what I want without mootools?

Comment: I ended up using Jens jquery solution instead, which works fine.

Answer (score 0):

IS the page loading as you've missed a ; after

```
<?php $theform->startForm($pageTitle)?>
```